# What does the createRange() function return

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code , which popups the highlighted text in the page . The problem I have is that the highlighted text always pops up at the end of the page ?

Does the create range return an integer value due to which I can make it popup at the middle of the line ? Is there any way that the pop up can be popped below the line under which the text is highlighted ?

The code so far is as follows

```
var getSelected = function() {
  var t = '';
  if(window.getSelection) {
    t = window.getSelection();
  } else if(window.selection) {
    t=window.selection.createRange();
  }
  return t;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).bind("mouseup",mouseup);
  $(document).bind("mousedown",mousedown);
});

var mouseup=function(){
  $('div#pop-up').show();
  var st = getSelected();
  document.getElementById("pop-up").innerHTML=st;
}

var mousedown = function(){
  $('div#pop-up').hide();
}
```

The above is the JS file for it . While the html just has a div with an id of pop-up

The problem isn't within the selector . But the problem is where it popups . It popsup at the end of the page due to the innerHTML but I want it to popup near where the text is selected . How do I do that ?

Comment: Maybe you want to check the docs at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535869(v=vs.85).aspx) or [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) or [this intro](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html)?

Comment: `createRange()` in your code doesn't return anything, since `undefined` has not the said property. You need `document.selection.createRange()`.

Comment: In the above code what should alert(t) or console.log(t) give me ? Because I am not getting even undefined or NaN or anything

Answer (score 1):

The selection range is an object that describes what text you've highlighted, in which element, and its general state.

The reason there's an `if` there is because this is a semi-recent (been around for years, just not 100% compatible, so few use it) standard, and different vendors used different implementations.

If you're on a browser which supports `getSelection`, then get the object that function returns...

...else, if your browser has a window.selection object, which holds methods for reading the actual selection, then do that.

It's like the old days of doing event-listening.
Now, everything is `.addEventListener`.

Once upon a time, it was:

```
if (document.addEventListener) { el.addEventListener(evt, func, false); }
else {
    func = function () { func.call(el, window.event); };
    el.attachEvent(evt, func);
}
```

Or `XMLHttpRequest` versus `window.ActiveXObject("msxml2.xmlhttp");`s...

Comment: Is there any way I can get the number of elements that were selected ? .Because I want to popup the information in an around the line where the text was selected . The text is getting selected alright .The problem is with where it pops ups

Answer (score 0):

remove the else if condition it should be just else in your case:

```
var getSelected = function() {
  var t = '';
  if(window.getSelection) {
    t = window.getSelection();
  } else  {
    t=window.selection.createRange();
  }
  return t;
}
```

Comment: Well I understand that part, but how do I make sure that the popup does not popup at the end of the page ? I want the popup to pop-up somewhere near where the text was selected

Comment: `else (window.selection) {` does make sense, or it should be `else {`? I never seen `else (condition)` without `if`

Comment: Original safety is preferred. Say some browser supports neither `window.getSelection()` nor `window.selection.createRange()`?

Comment: @RohanKumar there must be if condition for else condition to be applied but if and else if would not sense because if condition is not ended.

Comment: @C-link Do you think, your `else` part correct? See it carefully.

Comment: @C-link yes you are **wrong** `if(window.getSelection) {
    t = window.getSelection();
  } else (window.selection) {
    t=window.selection.createRange();
  }` should be `if(window.getSelection) {
    t = window.getSelection();
  } else {
    t=window.selection.createRange();
  }` Look at **[if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)**